# I never see my mechanic

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

In GTA 5 Online, I call my mechanic and the car spawns close to me, but I can't ever see my mechanic. Does someone know why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I had a long post of speculation, but then there's the [wiki entry](http://gta.wikia.com/Mechanic):

> As of Title Update 1.10, the Mechanic will no longer deliver the
>   player's car. This is possibly due to the Mechanic's tendency to crash
>   or otherwise damage the player's vehicles while delivering them,
>   because of AI glitches. It could also be due to the fact that the
>   Mechanic tends to drive away when there is a fight going on. Instead,
>   after the update, if the player asks for a car to be delivered, it
>   will immediately spawn near him.